# Default Value for gas in sendTransaction

Tags: transactions, gas

What is the default value for gas in sendTransaction api? Suppose I don't specify gas parameter in the sendTransaction api, what will be used?

Also, will this vary if it is a contract transaction instead of normal ether send transaction?

Comment: Do you mean the amount of ether, the third parameter?

Comment: No I mean contract.<methodName>.sendTransaction(<params>,{from: <acct-addr>, gas:<some-val> }) . If I skip the gas param altogether, what is the default value for it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Geth, the current default is 90,000 gas.

https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/e61035c5a3630e4f6fd0fb3e5346a4eed8cedc80/internal/ethapi/api.go#L50

`defaultGas = 90000`

But unless you're doing a plain Ether transfer (no `data` and costs 21,000 gas), it is best to specify a value to reduce chances of running Out of Gas.

The default gas doesn't vary according to the transaction.  The difference between invoking a transaction and a normal ether send is that the latter has empty `data` field, and this code makes no check on `args.Data`:
https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/e61035c5a3630e4f6fd0fb3e5346a4eed8cedc80/internal/ethapi/api.go#L1151

The code also doesn't change the gas for a transaction that creates a contract:
https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/e61035c5a3630e4f6fd0fb3e5346a4eed8cedc80/internal/ethapi/api.go#L1149