# I can not send transactions from my wallet contract

Tags: transactions, wallets, out-of-gas

Please, somebody help me!

I created the wallet contract 0x8cBcA499884Ac91065DAa258adF66d62e3D02c85

The Contract Creator was the account 0x19aE5032bD047BC24b5817B5C7512B0EbeC6626E

I've transferred some ether's to the wallet contract, but now I can not transfer any value from it.

Can someone check in the Block Explorer what happened to help me solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your transaction ran out of gas. Increase the amount of gas you send to the transaction.

[image]

The default gas for a standard account to a standard account is 21,000. The default gas for a standard account to a contract account is 90,000.

More information at [Default Value for gas in sendTransaction](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7054/default-value-for-gas-in-sendtransaction).

Comment: Thank you for your help!

I was able to send ether for the wallet contract.

However, I still can not send from the wallet contract to an account.

Comment: For example, I tried to send to account 0x3bD7B9B5f53A453b7B2AA70e8E5E85Df5767055e through transaction 0xc704e53ee8be1f824bd07b50e43e6486f6bd572e3547e5c4164dc6e4d7be4b85

In the Block Explorer, the message "Unable to locate Transaction entry" appears.

Note that the Contract Creator of the portfolio contract is the account 0x19aE5032bD047BC24b5817B5C7512B0EbeC6626E whose file I select when sending ether.

Are there any details I'm not sure how to do?

Here's the contract creation screen:

[https://etherscan.io/tx/0xc9b24516e0d554019e72ec24493741628897c07e697fe12eaf3471405f2f73a6]

Comment: [Corrected Link](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xc9b24516e0d554019e72ec24493741628897c07e697fe12eaf3471405f2f73a6)

Comment: * Where you read "portfolio", read "wallet". Take heed of my failing English.

Comment: Here's how I'm trying to transfer FROM the wallet contract TO an account:

Comment: In MyEtherWallet, I click on 'Send Offline'. I fill in the address of the WALLET CONTRACT and click on 'Generate Information'. I fill in the address of the ACCOUNT.
Then I fill in the transfer information. I select the format of the private key 'Key store file (UTC / JSON)'. I select the ACCOUNT file in my notebook, I enter the ACCOUNT password.

Comment: The ACCOUNT is decrypted. I click on 'Generate Transaction' and then on 'Submit Transaction'.
The message "Transaction submitted. TX ID: xxx ......" appears as if the transfer had occurred. However, there is no ether of the WALLET CONTRACT or no ether enters the ACCOUNT.

Comment: What is going wrong?

Comment: Can you please provide the details of how you created the wallet contract, including the source code if you have it available.